# How to get average of multiple lists in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose we have several lists :

```
List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9))
```

How do I get the average of each element of all lists? In which case, we will have 
`List((1+4+7)/3, (2+5+8)/3, (3+6+9)/3)` here.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want the avg of the 1st elements, followed by the average of all the 2nd element, etc:

```
List( List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9) ).transpose.map(x => x.sum/x.size.toDouble)
>res: List[Double] = List(4.0, 5.0, 6.0)
```

Comment: why do you want to introduce the transpose restriction... also how do you know that the lists are of length 3 ?

Comment: Why do u think transpose is a restriction?

Comment: Right, the length of 3 was not correct. Transpose is great if you know the lists are same length. If not, then what @jwvh has is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @marios is a good one, but what if the sub-lists aren't all the same length?  In that case `transpose` will throw:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections
>   have the same size

Assuming that you still want the average of all the nth values, even if not all sub-lists have n elements, this should work.

```
def getAvgs(lli: List[List[Int]]): List[Double] =
  if (lli.isEmpty) Nil
  else {
    val heads = lli.flatMap(_.headOption)
    heads.sum.toDouble / heads.length :: getAvgs(lli.filter(_.length > 1).map(_.tail))
  }

getAvgs(List(List(20,2,3,7), List(3,4), List(4,6,10)))
// res0: List[Double] = List(9.0, 4.0, 6.5, 7.0)
```

Comment: Can not you just map those lists to a sum and divide by length? What is the need of this code?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, look again at the question and at marios' answer.  The OP wants the average of all the 1st elements from each sub-list, and all the 2nd elements, 3rd elements, etc.  My proposed solution supplies the average for all Nth elements, even if not all the sub-lists have N elements. In my example output there is only one 4th element so the averaging all the 4th elements results in `7/1 = 7.0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val listOfLists = List( List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9) )
// listOfLists: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))

// if you wanted a simple avg
val listOfAvg = listOfLists.map(list => list.sum.toDouble / list.length)
// listOfAvg: List[Double] = List(2.0, 5.0, 8.0)
```

Lets say you want to have averages for `i`th elements,

```
val listOfIthAvg = listOfLists
  .flatMap(list => list.zipWithIndex)
  .groupBy({ case (i, index) => index })
  .map({ case (index, group) =>
    (index, group.map(_._1).sum.toDouble / group.length)
  })
  .toList
  .sortBy({ case (index, average) => index })
  .map({ case (index, average) => average })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using scala Lists (Rubio's answer to be dynamic):

```
scala> val dl =List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9), List(10, 11, 12))
scala> dl.transpose.map(_.sum/dl.length)
res5: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7)
```

Using Scala in Spark:

```
val valRDD = sc.parallelize(List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)))
valRDD.map(x =>  (1, (x._1, x._2, x._3, 1)))
    .reduceByKey( (x,y) => (x._1+y._1, x._2+y._2, x._3+y._3, x._4+y._4) )
    .map(x=> ((x._2._1/x._2._4), (x._2._2/x._2._4), (x._2._3/x._2._4)))
    .take(5).foreach(println)
```

Output: (4,5,6)

Comment: I don't think the OP is requesting a Spark solution